# JSF - message bundle always uses default properties file

Tags: jsf, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

I cannot get locales to work.

**System**

EAR and WAR

Glassfish: 3.12
Hibernate 4.2 - jar's on EAR and WAR
Mojarra: 2.1.11
Primefaces: 3.3
Omnifaces: 1.1

**Property files in source folder:**

> messages_de.properties <- using german language
>   messages.properties <- using english language

**faces-config.xml:**

```
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>messages</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

**Problem:**

Example the label and all other texts using the message bundle are wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:view locale="de">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputLabel for="postalcode" value="#{msg.postalcode_u}: *"/>
                <h:inputText id="postalcode" label="#{msg.postalcode_u}" required="true"/>
                <h:commandButton value="#{msg.save_u}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Required validation message: **Default validation messages use the correct language.**

Wrong message: `Postalcode: Überprüfungsfehler: Wert ist erforderlich.`
It should be: `Postleitzahl: Überprüfungsfehler: Wert ist erforderlich.`

**Setup:**

Glassfish 3.1.2
Mojarra 2.1.6 and also tested with 2.1.11

**Edit:**

**1.**
Using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()` to look into the same message resource bundle to display some custom faces messages does not work.

**2.**
I also have a second message bundle, currently also in source folder which is only accessed by the beans to display error messages:

> errorMessages_de.properties
>   errorMessages_en.properties

Those error messages created inside the bean are localized correctly using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()`!

**3.**
"Forcing" german language using following config still does not work. Messages are still retrieved from `messages.properties` and not `messages_de.properties`.

```
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>de</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

**New edit:**

When i start the server i get this warning:

```
Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1463)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getViewRoot(InitFacesContext.java:213)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeViewListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2026)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStop(StandardContext.java:4840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1049)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:998)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1024)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:330)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Edit2:**

The error message above is not relevant for the problem. See my own answer.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem in Mojarra 2.1.10. Are you somewhere doing an explicit `UIViewRoot#setLocale()` using the wrong locale in a request scoped backing bean? That'll probably explain the odd behaviour.

Comment: Updated to mojarra 2.1.11 and still same problem. No i am not setting it anywhere. (Had a locale session bean but deleted that for testing now.) I even created a new xhtml site with just the code i posted inside a simple form. Also deleted glassfish cache and removed apps and readded them. The example message makes no sense. Can a server setting cause that behavior? The locales definetly worked some time ago. Did not noticed when it stopped working.

Comment: Didn't you oversimplify the example and do you *actually* have a `<f:view locale="#{someBean.locale}">`?

Comment: I had before which I removed for testing. I only had a template file where I used `<f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}`">. My browser language is also set to `de`.

Comment: @BalusC I added some more informations what works and what not in the edit paragraph and a stracktrace from an exception which is sometimes printed.

Comment: According to the source code, `FacesContext` or `ELContext` would be `null` at that point. I suspect the `ELContext`. I'm unsure why. Are you using other frameworks together with JSF? Spring maybe? Have you registered a custom EL resolver?

Comment: I am only using hibernate (jar's are needed on client), primefaces and omnifaces. More info in question edited. I have no custom EL resolver. I hardly changed anything. I will try to remove my apps and create a simple empty web-app and test it and report here again.

Comment: I got the error. I narrowed it down that only the file itself could be the error and then a wrong formatted utf-8 special german character. But great thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an entry value in the properties file that escaped a german umlaut using utf-8 coding.

`ü -> \u00FC`

The problem was, that I missed the last `C` which made the properties file somehow unreadable!

Can't believe no appropriate error message was printed. If it could not be escaped why not just print the value like its done in many cases.

But that warning message is still present.