# jsf default locale issue

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I have the following configuration in faces-config.xml

```
<locale-config>
   <default-locale>tr</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>tr</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<resource-bundle>
   <base-name>i18n.texts</base-name>
   <var>text</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

and texts_en.properties, texts_tr.properties in the necessary directory. when I set locale to tr, tr messages are shown; when I set to en, en messages are shown; for other locales it is supposed to show tr messages while it shows en messages. any ideas?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750556/jsf-message-bundle-always-uses-default-properties-file. You maybe have a typo in a utf encoded character? Took me a lot of time to narrow it down to that error.

Comment: Not possible I am not using any non-ascii character neither of the text files

Comment: Turns out Locale Switcher addon on Firefox was secretly adding en_US to the accepted language. Everything is fine now; thanks for your time.

Comment: It was not Locale Switcher; it was Firefox itself.. sorry to bother, case closed